# Merge the [rocket-u2] and [u2] tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Both these tags are about the same topic, Rocket Software's U2 products.

[u2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/u2) has more questions than [rocket-u2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rocket-u2), which suggests merging the later into the former. On the other hand, the later is more distinctive, which makes it less likely someone will accidentally use the tag for some unrelated thing which happens to have the same name. Given that concern, I suggest [rocket-u2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rocket-u2) be the main tag and [u2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/u2) can be kept as a synonym.

Comment: I was about to migrate this to aviation.se ....